# Unable to extract the zip file if it contains any warnings

Tags: node.js, typescript, adm-zip

I have a zip file, on unzipping, it extracts all the files successfully but also gives the following warning message: "**There are some data after the end of the payload data**". However, when I try to unzip the same file using adm-zip, I am getting error "**Invalid or unsupported zip format. NO END header found**". For other zip files that do not give that warning message, it is working file. I am trying to find if there is any setting, where adm-zip ignore these warnings, and continue extracting. 
 Following is the code that I am using to extract the files.

```
const zip = new AdmZip('C:\\folder\\file.zip');
zip.extractAllTo('C:\\folder\\Result\\', true);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a zip file? It might be another archive format (7z, rar, ...) but with the wrong extension. In that case, AdmZip won't be able to extract it (unlike other tools such as 7zip or WinRar, which support multiple formats)

Comment: it is a zip file